# Clever way to use aspell to auto correct passage?

Tags: automation, spell-checking, aspell

I'm pretty new to aspell, but I just wanted to know if there was a way to scan a file using aspell and autocorrect all errors using the first suggestion.

Comment: Indeed it would be a very nice functionality ! I will have a closer look at : [http://weechat.org/scripts/source/spell_correction.py.html/](http://weechat.org/scripts/source/spell_correction.py.html/)

Comment: Is there any progress on this?